# Working with Chat feature in Quickblox in iOS

Tags: ios, quickblox

I want to implement chat feature in my app,its actually one to one chat,i have downloaded sample code from [quickblox.com](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios)

I have registered in Quickblox and just added my credentials in sample application which I downloaded, I'm getting the following issues

> 1.404 and Token is required.

I'm unsure whether I need to use API calls and where I can find API calls.

Can anybody please explain or provide me sample code to work.

Comment: Verify your credentials please, and what sdk version are you using?

Comment: pod 'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'TWMessageBarManager', '~> 1.7.2'
pod 'QMChatViewController'
pod 'QMServices'

Comment: There is no Quickblox sdk version, just open Quickblox.h file, version should be there.

Comment: this is because you did not create session.check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just implemented chat feature in my app. So I am elaborate you short description of how to enable chat in your app using `Quickblox`.Integrate sdk of `Quickblox` in your app or use pod.

First of all go through this link [quickblox ios chat tutorial](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios) than create users [register users from here](https://admin.quickblox.com/signin)
than in your app, login in `Quickblox` by using this code

**Method to login in Quickblox**

```
[QBRequest logInWithUserLogin: self.Name.text password:self.Password.text  successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user)
 {

 }
                   errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response)
 {

     NSLog(@"error: %@", response.error);
 }];
```

Dialog box means to create session between users like : one to one or group chat

**You need to create dialog box in order to enable chat, here is demo code of how to create dialog**

```
//create dialog

QBChatDialog *chatDialog = [[QBChatDialog alloc] initWithDialogID:null type:QBChatDialogTypeGroup];
chatDialog.name = @"Chat with Bob, Sam, Garry";
chatDialog.occupantIDs = @[@(55), @(678), @(22)];

// change id with your register user's id

[QBRequest createDialog:chatDialog successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBChatDialog *createdDialog)
 {

 } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response)
 {

 }];

// you can see created dialogbox in your quickblox admin panel in chat option
**//retrive list of buddies**

QBGeneralResponsePage *page = [QBGeneralResponsePage responsePageWithCurrentPage:1 perPage:10];
[QBRequest usersForPage:page successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBGeneralResponsePage *pageInformation, NSArray *users)
 {
     NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)users.count);
     for (int i=0; i<users.count; i++)
     {
         QBUUser *user = [users objectAtIndex:i];
         [buddyData addObject:user];
     }
     [self.buddyList reloadData];
 }
             errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response)
 {
 } ];
```

This is basic setup of `Quickblox` in your app. All details are already given in `Quickblox` tutorial.
If you need any help than just tell me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..I have done everything but unable to load users..Can u check my code..Shall i Share my app

Comment: jabber with XMPP..delegate methods are not getting called

Comment: i am using ejabber client

Comment: Shall i post another question or how to post code...Sorry for asking i am new bie

Comment: this question is related to quickblox,not ejabber client

Comment: just found very helpful tutorial for xmpp : "http://www.peerknowledge.net/?p=181".    delegate method are not calling, have you called "XMPPRosterDelegate" ?

Comment: @vani open Quickblox admin panel, go to the App overview, Settings tab. Check if there is "Allow to retrieve a list of users" selected.